# How to populate a cell in UITableView with an edited content?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Maybe I didn't ask it properly, because I'm not really sure how, so I will explain myself:

I have a simple notes app with two VC's:

1. table view controller - to list all the notes.
2. view controller - to create new notes.

In the table vc I have an unwindToList method that create an instance of the create notes page to get the note object that will be passed and if its not nil I will add it to the notes array and reload the data;

```
- (IBAction) unwindToList: (UIStoryboardSegue *) segue
{

    NMCreateNotesViewController *source = [segue sourceViewController];
    NMNote *note = source.note;

    if (note != nil) {
        [self.notes addObject:note];
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    } 

}
```

and an prepareForSegue method that will identify if this segue is a note segue (this is the segue I JUST want to preform editing in the create note page and when a user taps the save button, to save it in the same cell that the segue came from...):

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(UITableViewCell *)sender

{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"noteSegue"]) {
        NMCreateNotesViewController *destination = [segue destinationViewController];
        NSInteger indx = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:sender].row;
        NMNote *note = self.notes[indx];
        destination.passedInString = note.content;
    } 

}
```

In the view controller that create the notes I have a prepareForSegue method that looks like this:

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{

    if (sender != self.saveButton) return;
    if (self.textField.text.length > 0) {
        self.note = [[NMNote alloc] init];
        self.note.content = self.textField.text;

    }
}
```

Now, my problem is that when i'm editing a note from the noteSegue i'm creating a new note with the edited content instead of populating the same cell of the segueNote with the new edited content...

this is how the problem looks like:

[image]

Please help me to figure this out :/
Appreciate it!

Comment: I added a screen shot to show it to you visually. also, I have to remove the newNote code cause it didn't run the way i implemented it

Comment: Quite a mess, debug it with breakpoints is the easiest way to see what goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand your explanation.

You have a table view controller that is a master view controller and a note view controller that is a detail view controller.

The usual way to handle communications back from a detail view controller to it's master is to set up a delegate.

Define a delegate property in the detail (notes) VC that will point back to the master.

In the master's prepareForSegue, set `destination.delegate = self`.

Then, define a protocol for the delegate that the detail view controller will use to tell the master that the contents of a list item has changed.

You will probably need to tell the detail view controller the indexPath of the item that's being edited in the master-to-detail segue, and then before unwinding to the master, invoke a delegate method that gives the edited item to the master, along with it's indexPath so the master can save the changes and redisplay that cell.